# Laravel 5 Geolocation Dynamic Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, geolocation

Here's the main issue:

I need to render either a basic or dynamic page depending on whether or not the user allows geolocation. The dynamic page will make a number of calls through Google Maps API, thus changing the content of the page. **Where and how should I access geolocation, and make the respective API calls, while minimizing the negative effect on page load time.** I'm not asking for API calls, just where can I make them in this framework and workflow? My main issue is that geolocation is activated via `JavaScript` which is handled on the client side while the main app is built on `PHP` which is handled on the `server`side as explained here.

My current execution order is as follows:

1: User requests `domain.app/` which is given to route

2: `Route::get('/', 'NavigationController@indexWithoutGeoLocation');`

3: `NavigationController.php`

```
/* Load the home page without geolocation activated */
public function indexWithoutGeoLocation(){
  $theaters = Theater::get();
  return view('home',[
    'theaters' => $theaters
  ]); 
}
```

`Theaters` is a table which only uses `name` and `address` for this code. The theater's address will be compared to the user's geolocation.

4. `domain.app/`

Geolocation must be requested from the user so I include the following in the `<head>` of the page:

```
    <script>
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
        }
    </script>
```

[GeoCoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder) doesn't solve anything as I still have to transfer the JS to PHP.

My guess is to assign the contents of the `PHP $Theaters` that are passed when the view is loaded to a `JS var Theaters`. Then I'd be able to make all the Google Maps API calls in only `JS`. Serving the page becomes an issue now as it is in `PHP` and is completed before the `JS` even begins executing, resulting in the need to reload the page or use AJAX to erase the preloaded contents with the new data.

I'm new to Laravel and this seems a bit too hacky, so I came to SO for assistance, thanks!

Comment: Since this question is receiving down votes, could someone clarify what my question is lacking? The context is definitely not trivial and anyone attempting to do a similar functionality with laravel and geolocation would likely encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have similiar app that need to handle some logic of user location on server side, and of course you can handle your logic from PHP, you only need to pass your lat and long from your page to your controller

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "{{URL::to('your-routes')}}",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            long: position.coords.longitude
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // you can manipulation your html here
        }
    });
```

And if you need to calculate the distance of user geolocation and some location you can use this function

```
 function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) { 

 $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
 $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *    cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
 $dist = acos($dist); 
 $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
 $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
 $unit = strtoupper($unit);

   if ($unit == "K") {
     return ($miles * 1.609344); 
   } else if ($unit == "N") {
     return ($miles * 0.8684);
   } else {
     return $miles;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the AJAX. Regarding the distance I suspect I'll use the Google Maps API because I want the distance by road (as opposed to absolute distance that you calculate).